# Does App store accept Xcode 14 iOS app submissions with bitcode enabled?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, bitcode, xcode14

Does Apple accept Xcode14 builds with bitcode enabled?
Has anyone submitted it and gotten approval after [the deprecation of bitcode in Xcode14](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-14-release-notes#:%7E:text=Starting%20with%20Xcode,Xcode%2014.%20(86118779))?
I saw that it is mentioned that it's not accepted need to know if they are giving a buffer to us because of the tremendous app size increase(~80% in my case).

Answer (score 1):

No, and [the document you linked](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-14-release-notes#Deprecations) answers your question pretty clearly (emphasis mine):

> Starting with Xcode 14, bitcode is no longer required for watchOS and tvOS applications, and **the App Store no longer accepts bitcode submissions from Xcode 14.**
>
> Xcode no longer builds bitcode by default and generates a warning message if a project explicitly enables bitcode: “Building with bitcode is deprecated. Please update your project and/or target settings to disable bitcode.” The capability to build with bitcode will be removed in a future Xcode release. **IPAs that contain bitcode will have the bitcode stripped before being submitted to the App Store.** Debug symbols can only be downloaded from App Store Connect / TestFlight for existing bitcode submissions and are no longer available for submissions made with Xcode 14. (86118779)

Comment: Ya I was wondering if this has been mandated or since it's still in it's early stage they accept submissions with bitcode for now.

Comment: Judging by Apple’s word choice, it’s clear to me that this restriction is already in place and that they are no longer accepting IPAs from Xcode 14 which include bitcode.